# Play caller a sound file before dialing callee.

Tags: playback, opensips, openser

I am trying to play caller a file before dialing callee with opensips and rtpproxy. I used the makeann from rtpproxy to pre encode a  wav file didyou8r1c.wav(mono, 16bit, 8k), which gave didyou8r1c.wav.0 and didyou8r1c.wav.8.

Both files are located in /opt/test/ directory. My invite block is given below.

```
if (has_body("application/sdp")) {
                     if (rtpproxy_offer())
                            t_on_reply("1");
                            xlog("Trying to Play Caller file");
                            rtpproxy_stream2uac("/opt/test/didyou8r1c", "-1");
    }
```

But i see this error in rtpproxy logs.

Jan  4 04:07:08 66-226-76-150 rtpproxy[3977]: INFO:GLOBAL:handle_command: play request failed: session ZjU2NDU4Y2M1ODJlYjVmZjNmODY4MGI2MmU5ZTNkZjI., tags 253e361d;1/NONE not found

I hope someone can help me in figuring out what i am doing wrong.

Best Regards.